# Separate a string in 2 variables

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a string with 2 weblinks.

I've put an "@" symbol to separate them.

```
var yourString:String = http://www.weblink.nc/sons/silence.mp3@http://www.weblink.nc/sons/test.png;
```

Now, how can I separate those 2 weblink into 2 different variable (web1 and web 2)? 
(something with "`yourString.split(@)`") ? 
for this result :

```
var web1 = http://www.weblink.nc/sons/silence.mp3
var web2 = http://www.weblink.nc/sons/test.png;
```

Thank you !

Comment: _"How can I separate those 2 weblink into 2 different variable (web1 and web 2)? (something with "`yourString.split(@)`") ?"_ You need to use `.split` into an **Array** object. Count from zero. First part is at (offset) position `0`, second part is at pos `1`, third part is at pos `2` etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var yourString :String = "http://www.weblink.nc/sons/silence.mp3@http://www.weblink.nc/sons/test.png";
var stringParts :Array = new Array();

stringParts = yourString.split("@");

var web1 :String = stringParts[0];
var web2 :String = stringParts[1];

trace( "checking String web1 : " + web1 );
trace( "checking String web2 : " + web2 );

//trace( "checking Array slot A : " + stringParts[0] );
//trace( "checking Array slot B : " + stringParts[1] );
```

Which gives trace result of:

```
checking String web1 : http://www.weblink.nc/sons/silence.mp3
checking String web2 : http://www.weblink.nc/sons/test.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you please answer any of my emails by chance?